# How to return data type "Date" using AMFPHP

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, amf, amfphp

So, I cannot for the life of me manage to map a `DateTime` PHP class into an ActionScript `Date` class.
I need to return `Date` using AMFPHP. For example:

```
<?php
class Foo {  
  public $id; // int
  public $name; // string
  public $date; // DateTime
  public $bar; // custom object
}
?>
```

should go to --->

```
package {
  class Foo {
    public var id:int;
    public var name:String;
    public var date:Date; // native class
    public var bar:Bar;
  }
}
```

but I am getting

```
package {
  class Foo {
    public var id:int;
    public var name:String;
    public var date:Object;
    public var bar:Bar;
  }
}
```

I do not think someone here still uses this old stuff, but I guess it is worth a try. Thank you.

Comment: I'd say ask AMFPHP devs if this is possible. DateTime and dates in general are quite a bunch of legacy, perhaps AMFPHP devs have just failed to properly encode an incoming DateTime into what AS3 would recognize as a serialization of a valid `Date` object. If that would fail, parse the object inside at receive and convert it into a valid datetime by code.